# Automatically receive BLE Data in Android app when sent by device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Bluetooth Low Energy Scale and I'm coding an app for it.

I know the device name and the UUIDs for the service and characteristic.

All the example applications are manual where you have to click the device, the service, and the characteristic in order to get the data. I want to do it automatically.

For example, someone stands on the scale. The scale sends out weight data. The app sees the data being sent and stores it.

No user input required.

How do I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't this work when you pair your devices one time? Then the app can get information whenever the scale sends them (I think)

Comment: I'd assume the scale is a GATT server and you can [subscribe to characteristic notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#notification) to receive any new values.